# Reactor core: infinite Flux does not work with several subscribers

Tags: java, reactive-programming, flux, project-reactor

I'm sorting out with [React core](http://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core) and trying to create '[hot](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#reactor.hotCold) infinite' Flux with several subscribers:

```java
@Test
public void hotStream() throws InterruptedException {

  AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

  Flux<Object> flux = Flux
      .create(fluxSink -> {
        while (counter.incrementAndGet() <= 10) {
          try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
          } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
          }
          fluxSink.next(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
      }).log()
      .publish()
      .autoConnect();

  // first subscriber
  new Thread(() -> {
    log.info("[S] Subscribing first");
    flux.log().subscribe(s -> log.info("[*] S1: {}", s));
  }).start();

  Thread.sleep(450);

  // second subscriber
  new Thread(() -> {
    log.info("[S] Subscribing second");
    flux.log().subscribe(s -> log.info("[*] S2: {}", s));
  }).start();
}
```

But when the second subscriber has subscribed to the flux then process is stopping:

```shell
00:56:03.231 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
00:56:03.261 [Thread-0] INFO io.github.cepr0.demo.ReactiveTests - [S] Subscribing first
00:56:03.273 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.2 - onSubscribe(FluxPublish.PublishInner)
00:56:03.279 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.2 - request(unbounded)
00:56:03.286 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - onSubscribe(FluxCreate.BufferAsyncSink)
00:56:03.292 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - request(256)
00:56:03.403 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - onNext(1526939763402)
00:56:03.403 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.2 - onNext(1526939763402)
00:56:03.403 [Thread-0] INFO io.github.cepr0.demo.ReactiveTests - [*] S1: 1526939763402
00:56:03.403 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - request(1)
00:56:03.504 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - onNext(1526939763504)
00:56:03.504 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.2 - onNext(1526939763504)
00:56:03.504 [Thread-0] INFO io.github.cepr0.demo.ReactiveTests - [*] S1: 1526939763504
00:56:03.504 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - request(1)
00:56:03.605 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - onNext(1526939763605)
00:56:03.605 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.2 - onNext(1526939763605)
00:56:03.605 [Thread-0] INFO io.github.cepr0.demo.ReactiveTests - [*] S1: 1526939763605
00:56:03.605 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - request(1)
00:56:03.706 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - onNext(1526939763706)
00:56:03.706 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.2 - onNext(1526939763706)
00:56:03.707 [Thread-0] INFO io.github.cepr0.demo.ReactiveTests - [*] S1: 1526939763706
00:56:03.707 [Thread-0] INFO reactor.Flux.Create.1 - request(1)
00:56:03.713 [Thread-1] INFO io.github.cepr0.demo.ReactiveTests - [S] Subscribing second
00:56:03.714 [Thread-1] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.3 - onSubscribe(FluxPublish.PublishInner)
00:56:03.714 [Thread-1] INFO reactor.Flux.AutoConnect.3 - request(unbounded)
```

I expected that the second subscriber will start reading the stream **along with the first subscriber**. But this does not happen.

Could please someone explain why this is happening and how to solve it?

**UPDATED**

All I had to do is add the following line to the end of the test to prevent it from stopping:

```
Thread.currentThread().join();
```

Comment: _"then process is stopping"_  Presumably because the application (test) is stopping.

Comment: @zeroflagL you are right, I added `Thread.currentThread().join();`  to the end of the test - then everything has worked as expected.